# Get locale specific date/time format in Java

Tags: java, locale, date-format

I have use case in java where we want get the locale specific date. I am using DateFormat.getDateInstance

```
final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM,
                Locale.forLanguageTag(locale)));
```

This translates the dates but ja-JP this translates the date "17 January 2019" to "2019/01/17" but I need something like "2019年1月17日". For all other locales this correctly translates the date.

Please let know if there is other method to get this.

Comment: try just Locale.JAPAN https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-format-date-using-a-locale-based-format/

Comment: The `DateFormat` class is notoriously troublesome and fortunately long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalDate`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, Locale.JAPAN);
    Date today = new Date();
    System.out.printf("%s%n", dateFormat.format(today));
}
```

and `MEDIUM` acted exactly how you said

UPD: or using newer [ZonedDataTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) as Michael Gantman suggested:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ZonedDateTime zoned = ZonedDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL).withLocale(Locale.JAPAN);
    System.out.println(zoned.format(pattern));
}
```

Comment: FormatStyle.FULL also returns the date with the time "2019年1月17日 9時57分43秒 UTC". I do not want the current time.

Comment: To get only the date use `ofLocalizedDate` instead of `ofLocalizedDateTime`. Then you may also (optionally) use `LocalDate` instead of `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Sorry, there should be used DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate not DataTime. Fixed

Comment: Works fine now. Thanks a lot

Comment: Ok this is wired now, some locals have Day as well. Ex: for "fr-FR" output is 'jeudi 17 janvier 2019'

Comment: I don't speak neither Japanese nor French but maybe you should use custom format then: DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MMMM dd").withLocale(Locale.FRANCE); gives 2019 janvier 17 - maybe in France its common to give day name as well

Answer (score 3):

Just to mention: `SimpleDateFormat` is an old way to format dates which BTW is not thread safe. Since Java 8 there are new packages called `java.time` and `java.time.format` and you should use those to work with dates. For your purposes you should use class [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) Do something like this:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("..."));
```

to find out correct zone id for Japan use

```
ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()
```

Later on to format your Date correctly use class [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: This provides not only a very direct but also a very good answer to the question “Please let know if there is other method to get this.”

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use [`java.time.format.FormatStyle.LONG`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html#LONG):

```
jshell> java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(java.time.format.FormatStyle.LONG).withLocale(java.util.Locale.JAPAN)
$13 ==> Localized(LONG,)

jshell> java.time.LocalDate.now().format($13)
$14 ==> "2019年1月17日"
```

Comment: This is the solution that works on my Java 9. With `Locale.forLanguageTag("ja-JP")` too.